# Add Countdown Timer in application

Tags: java, android

I have made a quiz application which include 5 questions. I have made a ResultActivity page which displays result of the quiz.

Now I want to add a countDown timer of 20 sec for each question. When the Countdown timer finishes it moves to the next question automatically. When the questions are finished it should move to the ResultActivity page to display result.

I don't have any idea how to add the Countdown timer in it.

This is my Code:

```
QuizActivity.java

package com.example.triviality;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    public static int score,correct,wrong,wronganswers;
    public boolean isCorrect;
    static int qid=0;
    int totalCount=5;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioGroup radioGroup1;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butNext;
    TextView rt;
    boolean nextFlag =false;
    boolean isTimerFinished = false;
    static LinkedHashMap lhm = new LinkedHashMap();
     MyCountDownTimer  countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(10000 /*20 Sec*/, 1000);
    //final MyCountDownTimer timer = new MyCountDownTimer(20000,1000);
    public static String[] Correctanswers = new String[5];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //radioGroup1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        setQuestionView();
        // timer.start();
        rt  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rt);
        rt.setText("20");

        countDownTimer.start();

        butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                if(getNextQuestion(false)){
                //Start The timer again
                countDownTimer.start();
            }}
        });
    }


    private void setQuestionView()
    {
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("Times up","Times up");
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            if (getNextQuestion(false)) {
                //Start The timer again
                countDownTimer.start();
        }   
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            rt.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
            Log.e("Second Gone","Another Second Gone"); 
            Log.e("Time Remaining","seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }

    boolean getNextQuestion(boolean c){
        nextFlag = true;
        RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        //grp.clearCheck();
        RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        if(rda.isChecked()||rdb.isChecked()||rdc.isChecked()){
            qid++;
            Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
            grp.clearCheck();
            //wronganswers=
            if(!c && currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())){
                correct++;  
            }else{
                lhm.put(currentQ.getQUESTION(),currentQ.getANSWER());
                wrong++;    
            }

                if(qid<5){                  
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();

            }else{

                score=correct;
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent); 
                    return false; 
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                  "Please select atleast one Option",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            return true;
}
    }
```

//Display Result:
ResultActivity.java

```
package com.example.triviality;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    Button restart;
    Button check;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);
        TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult1);
        TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult2);
        restart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.restart);
        check=(Button)findViewById(R.id.check);

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Correct ans: "+QuizActivity.correct+"\n");
        StringBuffer sc=new StringBuffer();
        sc.append("Wrong ans : "+QuizActivity.wrong+"\n");
        StringBuffer sd=new StringBuffer();
        sd.append("Final Score : "+QuizActivity.score);
        t.setText(sb);
        t1.setText(sc);
        t2.setText(sd);
        QuizActivity.correct=0;
        QuizActivity.wrong=0;


        check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CheckActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

         restart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                QuizActivity.lhm.clear();
                QuizActivity.qid=0;
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_result, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you need some code provided for free for you, it won't work here.

Comment: [Countdown Timer in Android](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/01/countdown-example-in-android-custom.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way. Example of showing a 30 second countdown in a text field:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

   public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
   }
}.start();
```

The calls to onTick(long) are synchronized to this object so that one call to onTick(long) won't ever occur before the previous callback is complete. This is only relevant when the implementation of onTick(long) takes an amount of time to execute that is significant compared to the countdown interval.

For more help [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

I hope this is help you.

Comment: hello..i have almost done with my app.only two problems are there.can u help me to resolve it..1)if user does not select any option and timer finishes then it should move to next question by making the missed question answer as Wrong. 2) When i m clicking next button without selecting any of the option it is showing me toast message but timer is gettting restarted. I have edited my QuizActivity.java file with recent code..

Answer (score 0):

## [See CountDown Timer Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

**Make `MyCountDownTimer  countDownTimer` a  global Variable**

```
    // Global Variable
     MyCountDownTimer  countDownTimer; 
     boolean isTimerFinished = false;

    // Oncreate
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(20000 /*20 Sec*/, 1000);
    countDownTimer.start();

    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rda.isChecked() || rdb.isChecked() || rdc.isChecked()) {
                qid++;
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                grp.clearCheck();

                // wronganswers=
                if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
                    correct++;
                } else {
                    lhm.put(currentQ.getQUESTION(), currentQ.getANSWER());
                    wrong++;
                }
                getNext();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationText(), "Please Select an Option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });




 // Counter Class
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.e("Times up","Times up");

        isTimerFinished = true;

        getNextQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.e("Second Gone","Another Second Gone"); 
        Log.e("Time Remaining","seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}

void getNextQuestion() {
    nextFlag = true;
    RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    // grp.clearCheck();
    RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp
            .getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    if (isTimerFinished) {
        // Checking if some option is selected on time finished
        someName();         
    } else {
        // No Option Selected After Time Finished
        // Write your Logic here About Question Handling on "No OPTION SELECTED After Timer Finished..." My Logic May Be Wrong depends on how you are handling it.

        lhm.put(currentQ.getQUESTION(), currentQ.getANSWER());
        wrong++;
    }

    getNext();
}

void someName() {
    if (rda.isChecked() || rdb.isChecked() || rdc.isChecked()) {
        qid++;
        Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
        grp.clearCheck();

        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
            correct++;
        } else {
            lhm.put(currentQ.getQUESTION(), currentQ.getANSWER());
            wrong++;
        }
    }
}

void getNext() {
    if (qid < 5) {
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();

    } else {
        score = correct;
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next Intent
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());

    // Start The timer again
    countDownTimer.start();

}
```

Comment: thanx for help.but there is one problem.when the application is launched the timer is starting.but it is not showing timer like 20 19 18...0.And when it moves to next question after  timer finishes it  is not starting from 20 again.

Comment: Yes,now the counter is starting Automatically.But after completing last Question timer is still starting.And how can i show a flow like 20 19 18.....till 0.

Comment: Check this scenario, :- If user does not click on any of the answer and time is ended, then is it fetching the next question??? I think Not. Tell me. Then I will update the answer.

Comment: No it is not moving to next question.It is showing the Toast message and counter is starting again on the same Question.suppose the user does not click on any of the answer and timer finishes , can i move to next question counting that questions answer as Wrong.??

Comment: In private void setQuestionView().m getting countDownTimer cannot be resolved error..and if i comment countDownTimer.start(); the application is running but countdown timer is starting only on first question..and if any of the option is not selected it is not going to next question.

Comment: if user does not select any option and timer finishes it is not moving to next question.and even if i click next button the timer is not getting started again.and how to reset timer when i click on restart button of ResultActivity.java file

Comment: You have to handle such things. I can not develop your whole app

Comment: Yes bro..but atleast can u give some logic how to reset the timer by clicking the restart button..:)

Comment: Have you read the Count Down Timer Reference ??? [countDownTimer.start()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#start())

Comment: Yes..But my restart Button is in ResultActivity..and there i want to reset my countdown timer

Comment: Just restart the Quiz activity and Counter will restart again.

Comment: hello..i have almost done with my app.only two problems are there.can u help me to resolve it..1)if user does not select any option and timer finishes then it should move to next question by making the missed question answer as Wrong.   2) When i m clicking next button   without selecting any of the option it is showing me toast message but timer is gettting restarted.    I have edited my QuizActivity.java file with recent code..